# Getting files from directory into HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm in a situation where I need to be able to take all files from a given directory on either the local disk or a network drive and turn them into respective HTML elements. All of this must be done client-side, but these clients are dedicated computers for this task (of reading files and using them in a webpage it displays).

I've been looking at Node.js as a solution so I can use the file system fs to read the files from the folders, then pass the files (can I pass files like mp4s and PNGs this way?) to the browser-run-javascript to build the HTML on load with those files. I've come up with this because I've seen on other posts that browser-run-javascript doesn't have permission or access to do this by itself.

**My question is this:**
With Node.js installed on all of these machines and reading the files, is it possible (and how) for the browser to get information from Node without going over the network or through ports/HTTP requests?

Can it be done completely locally for each device?
I've seen Browserify and am unsure if that fits this scenario, so any verification would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Specifics for the scenario: The browser needs to generate a slideshow dynamically from files in the given folder on load. Things like pngs, mp4s, even links to browsers for use in iframes need to be read by either Node or the browser and turned into elements for the slideshow to toggle through.

Comment: What is the higher level use case for all of this?

Comment: @charlietfl Added and edited :)

Comment: So you run node as localhost server and build what you want the same way you would any web site. Or package everything into an electron app which is basically server, browser,  html and front end js wrapped into a desktop app

Comment: Found exactly what I needed in Electron. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible (and how) for the browser to get information from Node without going over the network or through ports/HTTP requests?

Yes, sort of.

You can skip going over the network, but you can't skip HTTP requests, because that's how browsers work.

You could make a node.js webserver program with [express](https://expressjs.com/) that reads and serves local files on disk and provides their contents in repsonse to HTTP requests. Then you install node.js and that program on these computers and launch it on a local port. Point a browser to `localhost:3000` and it will load your web application without requiring to be connected to the internet.

Just remember that node runs outside a web browser entirely. It has full access to the filesystem to do whatever you want, which a browser would never allow due to security concerns.

---

As an alternative to the browser entirely, you could try [electron](https://electronjs.org/) which is a bit more of a robust solution. It creates an app you launch on a desktop OS like any other app. It has direct access to the file system, and can render whatever HTML and JS you want in a window that looks nothing like a web browser at all. You could definitely hard code it to look in a specific directory, and display whatever is in there however you like on launch.